# Load .xaml page into textbox in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, ribbon

Hi I have a problem with loading .xaml page to textbox located in MainWindow. In previous implementation I used tabs, so I could simply write something like this

```
<TabItem Header="First Tab" Name="firstTab">
    <Frame Background="White" Name="firstTabFrame" Source="Tabs/firstTab.xaml/>
</TabItem>
```

Which propably handled enabled to load firstTab.xaml into mainPage. 
Now I have a Ribbon in which I have some kind of groups etc. How to load page firstTab.xaml into my mainPage (maybe to textbox? grid?) after clicking RibbonMenuButton clicked.

Comment: TextBox is a container for input text. Frame can load XAML code but you can't expect TextBox can do the same thing

Comment: So how can I handle this? Should I rewrote all old code? Or maybe I can use it?